# ajax ci formulate post var value to another view?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to write an ajax POST to send a value from one ci view to another. I've found lots of posts on this out there, but still haven't been able to get it right, maybe mostly because they show how to send data from form controls whereas I want to send data from a variable. On this view (Edit) I'm catching the current url which I want to send to the next view (Gallery) onclick of a jqm basic list item.

List (on controller):

```
$control .= '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="toGallery">';
$control .= '<li >';
$control .= '<a href="'. site_url() .'/mobilegallery/gallery/'.$x[0]->attributes()->indexI.'">[imgname.png]</a>';
$control .= '</li>';
$control .= '</ul>';
```

jQuery (on view):

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(event){
    var href = $(location).attr('href');

    $(".toGallery").live('tap',function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/mobilegallery/gallery",
            data: $('href').val(),
            success: function(data){
                var beforeUrl = href;
                alert(beforeUrl);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

On Gallery page I want to make the url a variable for later use. Do I create that variable in success as above, or do I get that value on Gallery page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your `url` variable around for later use (meaning subsequent page requests), you can simply store it as custom session data in your controller:

```
// $your_url would be the URL sent from the view via the AJAX request
$this->session->set_userdata('your_url', $your_url);
```

Now it would be available in any view like this:

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('your_url'); ?>
```

Comment: Just one thing - it's not the /mobilegallery/gallery/ url I want, but the current url, where the user is at when clicking to get to the gallery. That url will will be different for different users.

Comment: @Karin: You're already passing the current URL from your view to your controller, so just grab that value inside the controller and assign it to a custom session variable. I updated my answer to show how this would work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I haven't been able to get a value from the url from within my 'tap', though. And the ajax post in my original code above doesn't seem to be working either - I haven't been able to get the url value from there either.

Comment: @Karin: It should simply be `var href = location.href;`. You can then pass `href` like this: `data: href`. Also be sure that the controller you're passing data to accepts arguments.

Comment: I suppose something else in my code is causing my problem. I'll mark Colins answer as accepted and further problems will be made into new questions. Thanks!